# Why running homestead after vagrant/VirtualBox installtion I have version errors?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I try to run homestead, but I have an error :

```
$ cd ~/Homestead
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead: Box Version: >= 13.0.0, < 14.0.0
==> homestead: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
The box you're attempting to add has no available version that
matches the constraints you requested. Please double-check your
settings. Also verify that if you specified version constraints,
that the provider you wish to use is available for these constraints.

Box: laravel/homestead
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
Constraints: >= 13.0.0, < 14.0.0
Available versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.3.0, 0.3.3, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.4, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 4.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.1, 8.0.0.pre.alpha1, 8.0.0.pre.alpha2, 8.0.0.pre.alpha3, 8.0.0.pre.alpha4, 8.0.0.pre.beta, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.2.1, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.1.0, 9.1.1, 9.2.0, 9.3.0, 9.4.0, 9.5.0, 9.5.1, 9.6.0, 9.6.1, 9.7.2, 10.0.0, 10.1.0, 10.1.1, 11.0.0, 11.1.0, 11.3.0, 11.4.0, 11.5.0, 12.0.0, 12.1.0, 12.2.0, 13.0.0
```

In my system I have :

```
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ uname -a
Linux hoster-os 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
5.15.0-53-generic
x86_64
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ dpkg -s  virtualbox
Package: virtualbox
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/misc
Installed-Size: 109341
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1
Depends: adduser, iproute2, procps, virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules, python3 (<< 3.9), python3 (>= 3.8~), python3.8, python3:any, libc6 (>= 2.29), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libgl1, libgsoap-2.8.91, liblzf1 (>= 1.5), libopus0 (>= 1.1), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2), libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libvncserver1 (>= 0.9.10), libvpx6 (>= 1.6.0), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxt6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1), libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.2), libxcb1, libxext6
Suggests: vde2, virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Conflicts: virtualbox-2.0, virtualbox-2.1, virtualbox-2.2, virtualbox-3.0, virtualbox-3.1, virtualbox-3.2, virtualbox-4.0, virtualbox-4.1, virtualbox-4.2, virtualbox-4.3, virtualbox-5.0, virtualbox-5.1, virtualbox-5.2, virtualbox-6.0, virtualbox-6.1
Conffiles:
 /etc/default/virtualbox 903beafa3922607d1ac07950d9ae2d50
 /etc/init.d/virtualbox 651dc62d725baa7d040004ff22a7e433
Description: x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
 VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range
 of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on a
 Linux system.
 .
 This package provides the binaries for VirtualBox. Either the virtualbox-dkms
 or the virtualbox-source package is also required in order to compile the
 kernel modules needed for virtualbox. A graphical user interface for
 VirtualBox is provided by the package virtualbox-qt.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Virtualbox Team <team+debian-virtualbox@tracker.debian.org>
Homepage: https://www.virtualbox.org
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ dpkg -s  vagrant
Package: vagrant
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 3104
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 2.2.6+dfsg-2ubuntu3
Depends: libarchive-tools, curl, openssh-client, rsync, ruby, ruby-bcrypt-pbkdf (>= 1.0.0), ruby-childprocess (>= 0.6.0), ruby-ed25519 (>= 1.2.4), ruby-erubis (>= 2.7.0), ruby-i18n (>= 1.1.1), ruby-listen (>= 3.1.5), ruby-log4r (>= 1.1.9), ruby-net-scp (>= 1.2.0), ruby-net-sftp (>= 2.1), ruby-net-ssh (>= 5.1.0), ruby-rest-client (>= 1.6.0), ruby-vagrant-cloud (>= 2.0.3), ruby-zip (>= 1.2.2)
Recommends: vagrant-libvirt
Suggests: virtualbox (>= 4.0)
Breaks: virtualbox (>= 6.2)
Description: Tool for building and distributing virtualized development environments
 This package provides the tools to create and configure lightweight,
 reproducible, and portable virtual environments.
 .
 Vagrant uses Oracle’s VirtualBox to create its virtual machines and then
 uses Chef or Puppet to provision them.
Homepage: https://www.vagrantup.com
Original-Maintainer: Debian Ruby Team <pkg-ruby-extras-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Ruby-Versions: all
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ dpkg -s  virtualbox
Package: virtualbox
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/misc
Installed-Size: 109341
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1
Depends: adduser, iproute2, procps, virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules, python3 (<< 3.9), python3 (>= 3.8~), python3.8, python3:any, libc6 (>= 2.29), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libgl1, libgsoap-2.8.91, liblzf1 (>= 1.5), libopus0 (>= 1.1), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2), libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libvncserver1 (>= 0.9.10), libvpx6 (>= 1.6.0), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxt6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1), libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.2), libxcb1, libxext6
Suggests: vde2, virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Conflicts: virtualbox-2.0, virtualbox-2.1, virtualbox-2.2, virtualbox-3.0, virtualbox-3.1, virtualbox-3.2, virtualbox-4.0, virtualbox-4.1, virtualbox-4.2, virtualbox-4.3, virtualbox-5.0, virtualbox-5.1, virtualbox-5.2, virtualbox-6.0, virtualbox-6.1
Conffiles:
 /etc/default/virtualbox 903beafa3922607d1ac07950d9ae2d50
 /etc/init.d/virtualbox 651dc62d725baa7d040004ff22a7e433
Description: x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
 VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range
 of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on a
 Linux system.
 .
 This package provides the binaries for VirtualBox. Either the virtualbox-dkms
 or the virtualbox-source package is also required in order to compile the
 kernel modules needed for virtualbox. A graphical user interface for
 VirtualBox is provided by the package virtualbox-qt.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Virtualbox Team <team+debian-virtualbox@tracker.debian.org>
Homepage: https://www.virtualbox.org
hoster@hoster-os:~/Homestead$ dpkg -s  vagrant
Package: vagrant
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 3104
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 2.2.6+dfsg-2ubuntu3
Depends: libarchive-tools, curl, openssh-client, rsync, ruby, ruby-bcrypt-pbkdf (>= 1.0.0), ruby-childprocess (>= 0.6.0), ruby-ed25519 (>= 1.2.4), ruby-erubis (>= 2.7.0), ruby-i18n (>= 1.1.1), ruby-listen (>= 3.1.5), ruby-log4r (>= 1.1.9), ruby-net-scp (>= 1.2.0), ruby-net-sftp (>= 2.1), ruby-net-ssh (>= 5.1.0), ruby-rest-client (>= 1.6.0), ruby-vagrant-cloud (>= 2.0.3), ruby-zip (>= 1.2.2)
Recommends: vagrant-libvirt
Suggests: virtualbox (>= 4.0)
Breaks: virtualbox (>= 6.2)
Description: Tool for building and distributing virtualized development environments
 This package provides the tools to create and configure lightweight,
 reproducible, and portable virtual environments.
 .
 Vagrant uses Oracle’s VirtualBox to create its virtual machines and then
 uses Chef or Puppet to provision them.
Homepage: https://www.vagrantup.com
Original-Maintainer: Debian Ruby Team <pkg-ruby-extras-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Ruby-Versions: all
```

How that can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the vagrant tag: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.. The same is true for virtualbox. Please delete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and here is what worked for me:

Download an older version. This can be done on the official page on github (https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git), then go to ***tags***, select a version and download the zip archive with files.

Comment: Vagrant and virtualbox questions are off topic. here. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: @Face, I tried to install v13.3.0, but I got error :
git clone  https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v13.3.0
Cloning into 'v13.3.0'...
fatal: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v13.3.0/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Which format of the command must be ?